# Does this “Euclidean” sum of reciprocals of primes converge?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

The sum $\sum_{k=1}^n1/p_k$, where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime number, [is known to diverge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) as $O(\ln\ln n)$. However, prompted by Euclid, suppose that we restrict our choice of primes to a subset $Q:=\{q_1, q_2,...\}\subset\{p_1,p_2,...\}$, where $q_0:=1$ and $q_{n+1}$ is the least prime divisor of $q_0\cdots q_n+1$ (so that the first few elements of $Q$ are $2,3,7,43,13,53,\dots\,$). The question is: $$\text{does }\,\sum_{q\in Q}\frac1q\; \text{ exist?}$$

Comment: Considering that even the sum of the reciprocals of the primes of the progression $an+b$ , where $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers, diverges, my guess is that this sum still diverges. It could even contain every prime number. I do not think that we can decide this interesting question !

Comment: The sequence is called the [Euclid-Mullin sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Mullin_sequence). Shanks conjectured that it contains all the prime numbers.

Comment: @jjagmath A reasonable conjecture since the smallest not yet occured prime number $p$ should have a chance of $\frac{1}{p}$ to occur in the next step.

Comment: See also for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869211/euclid-mullin-sequence), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272958/are-all-primes-euclid-primes).

Comment: This is a very interesting problem, I am very interested in this sequence of primes. Please post an update here in the future if you ever have one.